# AngularJS Passing Scope Data From App Controller to Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Having an issue with trying to pass some scope data from my app controller to directive

http://plnkr.co/edit/github:plnkr/starters/v1.4.0/templates/angularjs?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', HomeCtrl])
    .directive('services', [
      function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            testData: '='
          },
          template:
            '<h2 class="service-name">Test: {{testData}}</h2>' 
        };
      }
    ]);

  /**
   * Home controller.
   * @param {*} $scope
   */

  function HomeCtrl($http, $scope) {
    $scope.testData = 'name';

  }
})();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css" />
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <services testData="testData"></services>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting undefined for the  scope "=" variable, testData
I can get it to render in the app using {{testData}}, but when passing it as an attribute, the  directive is not receiving the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your show code example modify to pass scope data to directive.

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', HomeCtrl])
    .directive('services', [
      function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            testData: '@testData'    //  ****************** note here 
          },
          template:
            '<h2 class="service-name">Test: {{testData}}</h2>' 
        };
      }
    ]);

  /**
   * Home controller.
   * @param {*} $scope
   */

  function HomeCtrl($http, $scope) {
    $scope.testData = 'name';

  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <!--  //  ****************** note here  -->
      <services test-Data="Hello World!"></services>
    </div>
  </body>
```